# Is the bond order in a resonance situation an average or can half bonds exist?

Tags: physical-chemistry, chemical-compounds

When drawing the lewis dot structure for $NO_2^-$

[image: Lewis Structure for $NO_2^-, I generated this using this http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=689aa5a01c216d8b16ed0250cebdc702 widget]

There is one double bond and one single bond so the molecule exhibits resonance and has bond order of 1.5. Does this mean the molecule shares 0.5 of an electron? Is the double bond oscillating between the two oxygen really quickly or is their actually half a bond? If we took a snap shot of the atom at an infintesimally small moment in time will one oxygen nucleus appear farther from the nitrogen nucleus than the other oxygen nucleus?

Comment: This may get a better answer on [Chem.SE](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok, is it possible to migrate the question?

Comment: The best way to understand Molecular Orbital Theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital_theory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to be aware of you are using a very primitive model to represent the molecule. Although the concept of "bonds" is ubiquitous to chemistry, there is not such a thing in reality. Even more, it does not exist in a more rigorous treatment. Many times we try to think things in terms of bonds due to it is simple to picture out.

Having said that,  no, bonds are not formed by some specific electrons, they just represents space regions where electrons tends to be between a pair of atoms in a molecule.

> Is the double bond oscillating between the two oxygen really quickly or is their actually half a bond?

No, the true state of the molecule is not a rapid oscillation among resonance structure, informally it is more like a weighted mean of resonance structures.

> If we took a snap shot of the atom at an infintesimally small moment in time will one oxygen nucleus appear farther from the nitrogen nucleus than the other oxygen nucleus?

Yes, but it is not a direct consequence of different bond orders nor resonance structures. It is related to [molecular vibrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_vibration) (change in distances and angles between atoms in the molecule that do not modify the mass center). I mean, it will happen even if all bond orders in the molecule are the same, or if there is just one relevant resonance structure.

Does it answer your questions?